# Euler's summation formula proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The following proof is from Apostol's book:
[image]

[image]

**Questions:**

1. On the first line of the proof, he uses '{}' just as brackets or do they have other meaning like $[x]$ being the floor function?
2. right before equation (6), why does the summation from $m+1$ up to $k$ become $kf(k)-mf(m)$?
3. at equation (6) when he substitutes back $x,y$ i'm not sure why are the two integrals equal?

Comment: On 2), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. They are simply brackets, no specific meanings.
2. Try to write all of them. Then the terms cancelled like this:
   $$
   3f(3) - 2f(2) + 2f(2) - 1f(1) = 3f(3) - 1f(1).
   $$
3. Since 
   $$
   \int_k^x \lfloor t \rfloor f'(t) \mathrm d t = k \int_k^x f'(t) \mathrm d t = f(k) - f(x).
   $$
   Same for the other term.

Comment: In the 3rd point here, should it not be kf(x) - kf(k) ?

Answer (score 2):

The proof in the question above has some mistakes. This is the newer one:[image]